# Django Manager - Override the default get_query_set to set a default "GROUP BY"

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am stuck with legacy db.  I want to modify the default queryset in order to work proficiently with the db, to do this I need to use a `GROUP BY`.  I know that I can do this which gets me the SQL I am after:

```
query = Variant.objects.all().query
query.group_by = ['name']
return QuerySet(query=query, model=Variant)
```

And this will result in the queryset that I am after. So I built a queryset Manager to help me out.  The problem is that it's returning the right values but when I do a count on it it's wrong.

```
class VariantQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def group_by_name(self):
        self.query.group_by = ['name']
        return self.filter()

class VariantManager(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return VariantQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
```

But then when I start playing with it..

```
>>> Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam")
[<Variant: RevA>, <Variant: RevA>, <Variant: RevA>, <Variant: revB>, <Variant: RevC_Fiendish>, <Variant: RevA>, <Variant: RevA_tapeout>]
>>> Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam").count()
7
>>> Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam").group_by_name()
[<Variant: RevA>, <Variant: revB>, <Variant: RevC_Fiendish>, <Variant: RevA_tapeout>]
```

So far so good.  7 ungrouped items, 4 with grouping.

```
>>> Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam").group_by_name().count()
7
```

So why is my count still stuck at 7 - it should be 4?  I've I thought _result_cache was holding the value so I set that to None in the method but no luck.  Any ideas why this is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.count()` actually creates a new query, with the fields removed and replaced with `COUNT(*)`.   It's actually not possible to group by a field *and* do a count on the grouped table in plain SQL. Basically, your originally query looked like this in SQL:

```
SELECT myapp_variant.id, myapp_variant.name, myapp_variant.etc, ...
FROM myapp_variant inner join myapp_project on myapp_variant.project_id = myapp_project.id
WHERE myapp_project.name='zam'
GROUP BY myapp_variant.name
```

The count query looks something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myapp_variant inner join myapp_project on myapp_variant.project_id = myapp_project.id
WHERE myapp_project.name='zam'
```

Note that it can no longer group. If it did you would end up with the following resultset:

```
COUNT
-----
    4 
    1
    1
    1
```

(In this case, 4 is the number of RevA records, then 1 for each of the others)

Because when you *group* in an aggregate query, you are telling SQL to make a row for each unique value in each grouped column. 4 different variant names, so 4 records! This is not what you want at all

You can confirm whether this is the problem this by outputting the query that Django generates:

```
>>> print Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam").group_by_name().query

>>> print Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam").group_by_name().count().query
```

There are really only two solutions to this problem:

1. Rewrite group_by_name so that instead of just grouping by a field, it actually returns a filtered queryset with just one record per name. Harder to do
2. When you need a "count" for the grouped queryset, just use `len()` instead, as in

   ```
   len(Variant.objects.filter(project__name__icontains="zam").group_by_name())
   ```

   or, in a template:

   ```
   {{ grouped_variants|length }}
   ```

Comment: Note that this means that the entire query will have to be evaluated (instead of the generally faster `count()` query) but I think most of the overhead here would be in the aggregation which you want no matter what. So you might as well do the real query and just call `len` on it.

Comment: This is exactly the path I followed.  Nice to know I was on the right track.  I did end up with the len(groups) as it makes the most sense.